# Standard version setting for Apex classes / Visual Force Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

You must have seen the below message several times during development. This message also shows current version and the previous version, which makes it clear that salesforce does maintain the version history of apex classes and VF pages.

Few questions:
Is this version data accessible? If yes how do we access?
Can we access the code component specific to a verison?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty confident this is not available, if it where we would more than likely see a facility to do so via the Metadata or Tooling API's, which we don't. I suspect in reality Salesforce are not retaining copies of the code, and that this is purely an incrementing counter to act as a kind of checksum between the view state held on the page at the time and its definition as per the controller class on the server. Sorry for the disappointing answer... maybe one day we will see a native source control integration?

Comment: That's my observation. The counter isn't even accessible via code or UI, unless you get that error while using view state.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yeah we will have to wait for that day :)